# How to update linux kernel automatically?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I have unattended upgrades installed, and it does job well, updating all the packages (except for kernel). When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` it returns:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

I can manually run `dist-upgrade` to update the kernel. However, I'm looking into automating this too. Can unattended upgrades also do `dist-upgrade` or I need to look for alternatives?

Edit: As suggested by @michal-przybylowicz, I have checked whether APT was holding packages, but all three return `was already not hold.`

Comment: Unattended-upgrades *already does* kernel updates. Somehow you have disabled it by preventing the kernel metapackges from updating. Any idea how you managed that? There are several possibilities, each is undone a different way.

Comment: @user535733 This is a new VPS with 16.04, I haven't manually done anything yet. Also found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/packages-have-been-kept-back-new-ubuntu-14-image), someone said it is expected behaviour to use `dist-upgrade` to update kernel packages.

Comment: If you "haven't manually done anything yet", then what do the unattended-upgrade logs say? Are you waiting a full cycle for u-u to run? Using `dist-upgrade` is correct *when you run apt manually*, which is a different case.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `unhold` these packages with this `apt-mark` command:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

Then You can run `sudo apt-get upgrade` again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but when I run it says `linux-generic was already not hold.` and similarly for other two packages.